# Iterating through and accessing JQuery object elements

Tags: jquery, object, iteration

I have a JQuery object of variables length that I need to iterate through. This is an example of the object:

```
{"entities":[["Undefined Farm","e8bb6d2f-be69-49a2-9851-28cdb6f936f2",0],["Home","ba72e1cf-72dd-415e-9d6f-d5d1493b19f3",1]]}
```

The above is what is outputted when I print `JSON.stringify(my_object)`.

The structure is basically what I would call (in Python) a dictionary whose key is "entities". The value is a list of lists. In the list of lists, every list is of length 3 where the first two elements are strings and the final element is an integer describing what index of the lists of lists that list corresponds to.

I would like to iterate through this list of lists and utilize all three parts of each list to do some stuff with `HTML`.

Just so I can be as clear as possible, if I were to do something like this is Python, it would look like:

```
for lst in my_object["entities"]:
    print lst[0], lst[1], lst[2]
```

I have to assume that there is something equally as easy in JQuery. So far, I have tried:

```
for (var p in my_object["entities"]) {
    alert(p):
}
```

But all that gives me is the integer (the last element of each list).

I also tried reading in the object as a string and then splitting it, but nothing printed out:

```
var p = my_object["entities"]
var arr = p.split(",")
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    alert(arr[i];
}
```

Comment: It's not giving you the last element of each inner array; it's giving you the key of the entry in the outer list. It's giving you `0` because `my_object["entities"][0]` is the first item in the array `my_object["entities"]`. It is coincidence that the last item of each inner array is also the index of the array.

Comment: @apsillers, yeah I figured it was something like that, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_object.entities` is an array of arrays

You can use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) statement

```
$.each(my_object.entities, function(_, entity){
    console.log(entity[0], entity[1], entity[2])
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4jWxd/)

in valina script

```
var p = my_object["entities"]
for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    console.log(p[i][0], p[i][3], p[i][4]);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P2puV/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var  obj = {"entities":[["Undefined Farm","e8bb6d2f-be69-49a2-9851-28cdb6f936f2",0],["Home","ba72e1cf-72dd-415e-9d6f-d5d1493b19f3",1]]}
var len = obj.entities.length;
console.log(obj)
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    var txt = "";
    var olen = obj.entities[i].length;
    for(var j=0;j<olen;j++){
        txt += obj.entities[i][j];
        if(j < olen){
            txt += ", ";
        }
    }
    $("body").append("<div>"+txt+"</div>");
}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/7G7zq/)